# Some Process.Start commands not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am working on visual studio 2012 with C# , but some of the commands are not working with visual studio.

I am trying to access

```
 Process.Start(Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "msconfig.exe"));
```

some other similar commands are not working. where as these functions are working fine in visual studio 2010 on same machine.
Please provide me some solution.

it is showing "Win32Exception ... the system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Any error/exception? What kind of project it is?

Comment: Win32Exception ...
the system cannot find the file specified

Comment: What do you mean by "are not working with visual studio"? Are you running these as part of an app, or part of a VS plugin? Your question is unclear at the moment.

Comment: @neelb2 have you compared those paths? (path from vs2010 and vs2012)

Comment: yes path from both are showing same

Comment: This is not a Visual Studio error.  Switch to .NET 4.0 and the code will work.  I think they added extra security in .NET 4.5.

Comment: so is there any other way to access these functions using .NET 4.5???

Comment: At a guess, you're running in a 32-bit process on a 64-bit machine and experiencing file system redirection. There's no `msconfig.exe` in the SysWow64 directory.

Comment: And the difference from 2010 to 2012 is that 2012 introduced the new default of AnyCPU (prefer 32-bit).

Comment: actually when i am getting **Environment.SystemDirectory** it is showing my **C:\Windows\System32** but still `msconfig.exe` and some others are not working where as `cleanmgr.exe` is working with the same.

Comment: @neelb2 - that's because if you attempt to access `c:\Windows\System32` from a 32-bit process on a 64-bit machine, the redirector still applies, and you *actually* access `C:\Windows\Syswow64` And `cleanmgr.exe` is present in both locations. The redirector had to work this way because so many (32-bit) programs had hardcoded paths inside (rather than using `Environment.SystemDirectory` or its moral equivalents)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summarizing what I put in the comments - you're seeing the issue because you're running in a 32-bit process that is then subject to [File System Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - your attempts to access the System directory get redirected to (by default) C:\Windows\SysWOW64.

This directory doesn't contain an `msconfig.exe`.

Visual Studio 2012, introduced a `AnyCPU` `Prefer 32-bit` option, and that is selected by default.

Best advice would be to switch your [build platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zekwfyz4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `64-bit`, or uncheck `Prefer 32-bit`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not beacuse of any security. As exception says file not found at disk. This is the problem with Visual Studio Project file configuration.

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "msconfig.exe");
if(File.Exists(path))
  Process.Start(path);
```

I simply tried this using default configuration and found that the if check itself failed.
In order to achieve this you will have to change the platform for project. By default the Visual Studio environment is taking x86 always even though you are running 64-bit OS and selecting Any CPU. 
Below are the settings for your program to work.
`Right click on project` in Solution Explorer and Select **Settings -> Build -> Plateform target ->** Select **x64.**

Have a look on below image for visual representation of settings:

[image]

Mark as answered if fixed your problem